# SSLHandshakeFailed in Flash Player 11,1,102,55 (Chrome/FMS/RTMPS)

Tags: google-chrome, flash-player-11, rtmps

I have an application working with FMS through RTMPS. In IE and Firefox it works fine with any flash player. But in Chrome and Flash Player 11,1,102,55 I got an error "NetConnection.Connect.SSLHandshakeFailed" when I am trying to establish the RTMPS connection to the server. For debug version of the same as well as older flash player version it works fine. There are no special steps to reproduce. Just start the FMS server, install the Flash Player 11,1,102,55 version in Chrome, and try to connect to the server.

I was unable to find any workarounds so far, and I am wondering if somebody has the same problem and know how to resolve it?

Also, I reported about the problem to Adobe, but it looks like it takes a lot of time even verify the bug on the Adobe side.

Thanks for any ideas!